# Predominant vs. predominating

Tags: word-choice, verbs, adjectives

> While **all states face similar industrial waste problems, the predominating industries and the regulatory environment of the states obviously determines** the types and amounts of waste produced, as well as the cost of disposal.
>
> A. all states face similar industrial waste problems, the predominating industries and the regulatory environment of the states obviously determines
> B. each state faces a similar industrial waste problem, their predominant industries and regulatory environment obviously determine
> C. all states face a similar industrial waste problem; their predominating industries and regulatory environment obviously determines
> D. each state faces similar industrial waste problem, the predominant industries and the regulatory environment of each state obviously determines
> E. all states face similar industrial waste problems, the predominant industries and the regulatory environment of each state obviously determine

This is a GMAT question. One option is correct among the five options given.
Correct Option: **E**

I have questions about *predominant* and *predominating*. Which one is correct here and for what reason?

Answer (score 1):

The road to **E** as the correct answer to this multiple-choice question doesn't run through the distinction between *predominating* and *predominant*. Rather, you get there through process of elimination—because each of the other options has a disabling flaw (as GMAT views the world of language). Let's walk through the options.

> **A.** all states face similar industrial waste problems, the predominating industries and the regulatory environment of the states obviously determines

The basis for rejection here is the use of *determines* (a singular verb) with a plural subject ("the predominating industries and the regulatory environment of the states"). **A** is out.

> **B.** each state faces a similar industrial waste problem, their predominant industries and regulatory environment obviously determine

The basis for rejection here is the mismatch between a singular subject ("each state") and a plural linked possessive pronoun ("their"). GMAT wants you to conclude that the proper possessive pronoun in this version of the sentence is *its*. **B** is out.

> **C.** all states face a similar industrial waste problem; their predominating industries and regulatory environment obviously determines

The basis for rejection here is the use of *determines* (a singular verb) with a plural subject ("their predominating industries and regulatory environment"). **C** is out.

> **D.** each state faces similar industrial waste problem, the predominant industries and the regulatory environment of each state obviously determines

The basis for rejection here is the use of *determines* (a singular verb) with a plural subject ("the predominant industries and the regulatory environment of each state"). **D** is out.

> **E.** all states face similar industrial waste problems, the predominant industries and the regulatory environment of each state obviously determine

This version of the sentence has no subject-verb agreement problem, no pronoun number issue, and no other disqualifying grammatical difficulty. We've got a winner!

As you can see from this analysis, standardized test questions often seek to confuse test takers by setting up false conflicts (here, a supposed conflict between *predominating* and *predominant*) to distract readers from what the test creator considers the actual errors in a series of choices. It's a sneaky business—and the standardized test industry puts a lot of effort into doing it effectively.